# a:hover box-shadows using PIE

Tags: css, hover, css3pie

I am looking for some help using CSS3 Pie,

I have applied it to certain aspects of my site so that they are able to use  box-shadows in earlier versions of IE and it seems to work fine, however when I am trying to apply it to a:hover it just simply won't pick up and no styling is being applied.

Incase anyone is unsure what CSS3 PIE is please check out: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no details provided, I can only recommend you to use the Javascript version of the PIE - [PIE.js – PIE JavaScript edition](http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/)
You need to add hover functions with Javascript and inside of the use the PIE.attach method.

The other hook - is to set zero properties on elements that are not 'hovered'
for example

```
a {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  behavior: url(/path/to/PIE.htc);
}
a:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```